# How I can fetch data from snowflake Views using sqlalchamy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have database in snowflake inwhich there are some Views. I have the create the connection using sqlalchamay and i can easily execute my queries on tables.

But my Question is is there any way in sqlalchamy/or any other orms of python that i can execute my query the on snowflakes View.

```
def generate_session(self):
    try:
        engine = self._get_engine()
        self._table = func(self._table_name, MetaData(), autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
        self._session = Session(engine)
    except Exception as exc:
        LOG.error('Failed to generate database session', error=exc.__str__(), database=self._database)
        raise exc
```

and i using it like this.

```
self._session.query(self._table).filter_by(**some_filter_by_query).all()
```

also i have seen this link, which say it's possible. but i am unable to understand.

https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/wiki/Views

thanks

Answer (score 1):

So after doing research for some hours i got the answer..
so the solutio is we need to make views=True while creating the metaclass object.

```
engine = self._get_engine()
        metadata = MetaData(engine)
        metadata.reflect(views=True)
        self._table = Table('MONTHLY_OVERVIEW', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
```